# Compositing/flattening images in Rails with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm building a Rails application where a user can upload an image which is automatically cropped to a certain size, then they can choose an overlay which is exactly the same size as the cropped image.

What I want to do is composite or flatten the two images and save it as a single image - I've looked at the Image Magick documentation, but I can't see how to apply the example they give:

```
composite -gravity center smile.gif rose: rose-over.png
```

to work with Paperclip.

Also, the example references two specific images, but I'm wondering how I can pass in a variable (the user uploaded image) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use a paperclip processor.

Here is the high level description:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#custom-attachment-processors

Here is a gist example of using composite (recommended here https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/978):

https://gist.github.com/708077

Comment: has anyone used this??